# Cayley's theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups

As according to Cayley's theorem "Every group is isomorphic to a subgroup of some symmetric group".  Now my question is: the additive group of real numbers is isomorphic to which permutation group...

Comment: These questions are easier to answer if you recall the full statement of Cayley's theorem: "Every group $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of *the symmetric group on $G$* (where $G$ is now being considered as a set)". Thus, the additive group of real numbers has to be isomorphic to a group of permutations of the real numbers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is unfortunately not interesting. A permutation $\pi$ of the real line is called a *translation* if there exists a real number $a$ such that $\pi(x)=x+a$ for all $x$. The translations form a subgroup of the permutation group of $\mathbb{R}$, and this subgroup is isomorphic to the reals under addition.

Comment: The fact that a question like this could have an uninteresting answer is fascinating...

Comment: When talking about real numbers, the notation $\pi$ for a transformation is unfortunate.

Comment: Is it less intetesting than any other Cayley embedding? Why?